# Create a splash screen with white background and PNG with transparent colours on top

Tags: android

We we have a mono for android application which is currently displaying a nice splash screen with a logo PNG centred on the screen.

However, the screen background is black, meaning that the logo - which has a transparent background - doesn't show up so well.

My theme is currently set up as follows:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Where 'splash.png' is my splash logo image.

Setting the background using

```
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
```

overrides the splash image background.

Is it possible to define the theme to have a white background, with the splash.png on top of it?

The alternative is for us to amend slpash.png to have a white background, rather than transparent, but I'ld like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to just use an ImageView and set the logo to that to allow you to set the background colour of the container layout to whatever you please?

... Perhaps you can make an xml file with a layered/level list drawable composed of a background and the logo as two separate levels/layers and apply that xml file to your style background/windowbackground as a drawable?

Please check out: [Drawable Resource| Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: It might be, but I'd like to use the theme mechanism for the splash if possible.

Comment: Thanks for amplifying your response - I can see how layers might work, but am struggling to work out how to incorporate this in my style. Can you give an example of how I might achieve this?

Comment: Looking more at how themes work, I don't see how it's going to be possible to add layers. Therefore I think the best solution is going to be to make the splash PNG the right size to fill the screen with the correct colours.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawable splash xml, use a Layer-List to contain each item, then setup your background as one item and your logo as another. That's what I've been doing at least :)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/backgroundb" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="center" android:src="@mipmap/launchicon" />
</item>
```

Might be a bit late mind you, I've just realised how old this question is lol